# Como resolver o erro MSBUILD : error MSB3428 do node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou tentando instalar um package localizado no diretório que estou com o comando `npm install` do node.js, porém após instalar alguns dos pacotes recebo o erro:

> npm install error - MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   “VCBuild.exe”

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Após pesquisar um pouco, tentar reinstalar o `.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)` e rodar o comando `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`, continuo não conseguindo instalar e recebendo o mesmo erro.

Sei que o pacote esta correto e tem tudo que precisa, pois outros colegas conseguiram instala-lo.

Estou rodando o node.js versão x64 no windows 10 x64, alguma sugestão para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tem o Visual Studio 2005 instalado? Reiniciou o win após a reinstação do .NET Framework e logo após tentou o npm install --global --production windows-build-tools?

Comment: Tenho o visual Studio 2017 instalado e já tentei reiniciar após o comando de install que você mencionou